# How can I label and reference a table without using the table environment

Tags: tables, labels

I want to be able to refer to tables that are not enclosed in the table environment. My reason for doing this is that these are statistical tables (yes a relic of times long gone) that I don't want to float. I need them to stay put because I haven't got enough years of life left to deal with them moving wherever they want.

So what I would like to do is something like this:

```
    \begin{tabular}{ll}
     1 & 2 \\
     3 & 4 \\
    \end{tabular}
    \label{tab:B-1}
    ...
    In Table \ref{tab:B-1} on page \pageref{tab:B-1}
```

Thanks

Comment: package `capt-of` https://www.ctan.org/pkg/capt-of

Answer (score 4):

Well, if you allow captions, then one solution would be to use the ["capt-of"](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/capt-of) package. And, to my mind, you can't reference anything by number if you don't use the number there, so caption is almost inevitable.

You'll be able to have

> \captionof{table}{some caption}

```
\captionof{table}{Some caption}\label{tab:B-1}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
     1 & 2 \\
     3 & 4 \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{centering}

    ...
    In Table \ref{tab:B-1} on page \pageref{tab:B-1}
```